# How to use life cycle methods /functions in React Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

What's wrong with the following component?
Its throws an error while the original class based version with life cycle methods works fine?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const  NewsHook = ()=> {
  const [mount, setMount] = useState(false);
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setMount(true);
    axios.get('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react')
        .then(result => {
                if (mount){
                    setNews({
                        news: result.data.hits,
                    })
                }
            }
        );
    return () => {
      setMount(false);
   }
  }, [mount]);

  return (
        <ul>
            {news.map(topic => (
                <li key={topic.objectID}>{topic.title}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
  );
}
export default NewsHook
```

Comment: hier is the original class based version with life cycle methods

Comment: "it throws an error". Please add the error

Comment: Well. One of the errors I see is the you set news to setNews({news: result.data.hits}) which is news.news[]  but when you map the topic you map an object not array of objects. The correct map would be news.news.map()

Comment: i was not able to post the class based version with only 39 chars which was rejected as too long

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you should map on news.news because you are setting state for news like this
setNews({  news: result.data.hits   })
or just use setNews(result.data.hits);

Comment: just change `setNews({
                        news: result.data.hits,
                    })` to ` setNews(result.data.hits)`. It will work

Comment: changing to this doesnt work
```
news.news.map(topic => (
```

setting like doenst work either:
```
 setNews({ news: result.data.hits, });
```

Comment: Could you show us what `result.data.hits` looks like please ?

Comment: `result.data.hits` is just an array of string

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the data is fetching. So news will be still null. Either using async to solve the problem or doing in this way :)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [mount, setMount] = useState(false);
  const [news, setNews] = useState([{ new: null }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMount(true);
    axios
      .get("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react")
      .then(result => {
        setNews({ new: result.data.hits });
      });

    return () => {
      setMount(false);
    };
  }, [mount]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {news.new == null ? (
          <h2>Loading</h2>
        ) : (
          news.new.map(item => {
            return <li key={item.objectID}>{item.title}</li>;
          })
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it will solve your problem.
Hope it is help :)

Comment: Thanks all.The suggested changes do not work.
I still get the error:

**TypeError: news.map is not a function**

Comment: Hi bro, please check the edited answer. I tested it, it should be working

Answer (score 0):

the solution was that the following:

```
setNews(result.data.hits);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to set a state of mount because the useEffect will work automatically when the component mounts and if you want it to work just ones, you add empty array [] as the second argument

and you have to wrap your Axios request inside useEffect to an async function like that:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const  NewsHook = ()=> {
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getNews = async () => {
      const result  = await axios.get('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react');
      setNews({
        news: result.data.hits,
      })
    };
    getNews();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {news.map(topic => (
        <li key={topic.objectID}>{topic.title}</li>
       ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default NewsHook
```